# CentOS 7.7.1908 - Can't install on NUC

Tags: centos, system-installation

I have a new NUC (NUC11ATKPE) and I need to install CentOS 7.7.1908 on it. Vendor is specifying that version for the install of their witness software.

I've tried creating the bootable USB with a number of tools, including dd. All have the same results. When I select Install CentOS Linux 7, the screen just goes black.

I've tried setting `nomodeset` and `modeset=1`. I also tried `nomodeset text` to see if that got me anywhere. But always the same, just a black screen. No ability to get to a console with various keystrokes I tried.

I'm at a loss here.